# C# stop user inputting a character/string instead of integer

Tags: c#

I am asking users to input a int for their age but the program crashes when they input a string(obviously).

How would I go about allowing them to input a char/string but the program to display a funny message and then quit?.

This is what I have got so far:

```
      Console.WriteLine("Please can you enter your age");
        int userage = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (userage < 16)
        {

            var underage = new underage();
            underage.text();
        }
        else if (userage>122)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No one has ever reached this age and so you can't possibly be this old");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a different age next time!");
            Console.WriteLine("Unless you really are this old, in which case don't work!!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit the program.\n");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else if(userage<122)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ah brilliant, you are old enough to use our services\n");
            Console.WriteLine("We shall continue as first planned\n");
        }
        else
        {

        }
```

Comment: Use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Where in that code would I add int.TryParse?

Comment: At the beginning after you've read the user-input. Store the `Console.ReadLine` in a string variable and use that as argument for `int.TryParse`. `Int.TryParse` returns a `bool`. If it's true the int-variable will have the valid value, if it's false you know that the user-input was not a valid integer.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Please can you enter your age");
            int userage;
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userage))
            {
               //your if block
            }
            else
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Your input is funny and I am a funny message\n");
               Environment.Exit(0);
            }
```